# Add Attribute to multiple subcomponent Tags

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, elementref

I use Alfresco ADF, which uses Material Design. They have a datatable Component, which in fact uses the the Angular Material Table.

Now in order to implement a drag and drop feature, I need to add `draggable="true"` on every `mat-row`tag.

How do I accomplish this? I heard you should use Renderer2 and ElementRef, in order to access the DOM element and change its attributes.

Or is there another way to this?

Answer (score 0):

In angular material, you can define a [table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) like this, which allows you to add your attribute to the `mat-row` elements.

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="myColumn">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> My Column </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          Some content...
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row draggable="true" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

  </mat-table>
```

[Example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDtFX.png)

Comment: Sorry, but how? is the #table already available? See as I said, I have an extra layer of abstraction with the Alfresco ADF. They have a component, which then uses the material table. So I don't have direct access

Comment: I see. If you want to stick with the Alfresco abstraction you could try to get all the `mat-row` elements with something like `table.getElementsByTagName("mat-row")`, then loop over the array and do `item.setAttribute("draggable", "true")`